# Sum based on another table's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I want to combine:

TABLE1: The results are quarterly by ID:

| ID | Date | Notional |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 468850 | 30/06/2021 | 188.600.098,35 |
| 468850 | 30/09/2021 | 187.528.261,37 |
| 468850 | 31/12/2021 | 186.440.182,86 |
| 468850 | 31/03/2022 | 185.312.592,91 |
| 468850 | 30/06/2022 | 184.145.359,69 |

Table 2: Have a different set of results Monthly:

| ID | Date | Yield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 468850 | 30/04/2021 | 67.6903 |
| 468850 | 30/05/2021 | 69.9467 |
| 468850 | 31/06/2021 | 67.6903 |
| 468850 | 31/07/2021 | 69.5479 |
| 468850 | 30/08/2021 | 69.5479 |
| 468850 | 30/09/2021 | 67.3044 |

I've been trying to cross these tables by ID and return the results quarterly (as in table one) summing the field Yield, the ideal result would look like this for the first two quarters:

| ID | Date | Notional | Yield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 468850 | 30/06/2021 | 187.528.261 | 2.053.275 |
| 468850 | 30/09/2021 | 186.440.182 | 2.064.003 |

Where Yield is the summation of every month's value. I tried the below code, but it does not seem to work:

```
SELECT  A.ID,
A.Date,
SUM(B.Yield) 
FROM Table1 A, Table2 B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
AND A.Date = B.Date
GROUP BY A.ID,
        A.Date
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Perhaps because your data is incorrect? Both 30/05/2021 and 31/06/2021 are not month-end values. Are those column defined as strings and some evil process has allow invalid dates to enter your table? But if you want to sum your monthly values to a quarterly value, then you cannot join on Date. You will need to convert the quarterly date in Table1 to the associated monthly range to "gather" the rows from Table2.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly , here is how you can do it:

```
select a.*,b.Yield from 
Table1 a
join (
  select ID, YEAR(date) year, DATEPART(QUARTER ,date) quarter, sum(Yield) Yield
  from Table2 
  group by ID, YEAR(date), DATEPART(QUARTER ,date) 
)b on a.ID = b.ID 
and Year(a.Date) = b.year
and DATEPART(QUARTER ,a.date) = b.quarter
```